# Number of threads of Intel MKL functions inside OMP parallel regions

Tags: c, multithreading, intel-mkl, openmp

I have a multithreaded code in C, using OpenMP and Intel MKL functions. I have the following code:

```
    omp_set_num_threads(nth);
#pragma omp parallel for private(l,s) schedule(static)
for(l=0;l<lines;l++)
{
    for(s=0;s<samples;s++)
    {
        out[l*samples+s]=mkl_ddot(&bands, &hi[s*bands+l], &inc_one, &hi_[s*bands+l], &inc_one);
    }
}//fin for l
```

I want to use all the cores of the multicore processor (the value of nth) in this pramga.
But I want that each core computes a single mkl_ddot function independently (1 thread per mkl_ddot function).

I want to know how many threads are used by the mkl_ddot function in this case. I read in some forums, that by default mkl functions inside a pragma parallel run using only 1 cores (thats what i want).
But I am not sure about this behaviour and I can not find the specific section in the manual explaining this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct - by default MKL runs with a single thread if it detects that it is being called from inside a parallel region. I have explained the way to change this behaviour in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722253/1374437). You can simply invert the boolean parameters there to make sure that MKL would only use a single thread.

Yet, if you only want MKL functions to run single-threadedly, e.g. you only use it from inside parallel regions, you'd better link with the sequential MKL driver instead. With Intel's compiler this is easy - just specify `-mkl=sequential`. For other compilers you should look into the library's manual for how to link your program against the sequential driver.

Comment: do you know if this automatic 1-thread-usage calls inside an OMP parallel for region happens as well for the CRAY - BLAS library ?

Comment: @velenos14 it's MKL-specific. No idea about CRAY's library. Check the docs perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The [Intel MKL Library](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lin/MKL_UG_managing_performance/Using_the_Intel_MKL_Parallelism.htm) uses OPENMP threading software for multithreading. The number of threads created will be based on the enviornment variable "`OMP_NUM_THREADS`". The default value for `OMP_NUM_THREADS` depends on the [Intel MKL version and OPENMP libraries](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lin/MKL_UG_cluster/Setting_the_Number_of_Threads.htm).

But in your case, you are doing a nested parallelism. But by default the nested parallelism is turn off. Hence the number of threads used by mkl_ddot function will be ONE (which means no parallelism at mkl_ddot function level).

You can enable the nested parallelism by invoking `omp_set_nested(1)`. By this way, in your case, the nested parallelism will be enabled and more than one thread will be used by mkl_ddot function.